# Responsive mobile navigation issues when you stretch the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am working on a new responsive site and I have an issue with the mobile menu. The link is http://kaniamea.com/resource/
When you see the site with a smaller screen and you click the mobile icon the following happens if you stretch the screen http://www.kaniamea.com/1.jpg The whole navigation expands instead of the content area. if you keep on stretching the screen still you will see the nav styles only. I would be thankful for any feedback on what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new css @media query with the style you'd prefer. Here's an example:

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
<!--set styles you want users to see at any screen size 768px and smaller (mobile-size)-->
}
```

When your screen is wide enough/small enough to get the error (you'll have to mess around with it and inspect the element that's giving you issues), just set the width to that element so it won't stretch/shrink anymore.

Might be worth it to check out [@media and how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I found the problem. There was a broken css in the main style sheet. Now it works.